# Adding new attribute to Object after it's created using method (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, object

I am trying to add an attribute to an object after it's been created using a method from within the object Class. I'd like to put this code in the def set_sell_by and def get_sell_by methods, if this is possible. So, in the end I'd like to do apple.set_sell_by(10) and then get that value later by doing apple.get_sell_by to check if the item has 5 days or less left to sell it.

```js
class Grocery_Inventory
 attr_accessor :product, :store_buy, :quantity, :serial_number, :customer_buy
 def initialize(product, store_buy, quantity, serial_number, customer_buy)
  @product = product
  @store_buy = store_buy
  @quantity = quantity + 5
  @serial_number = serial_number
  @customer_buy = customer_buy
 end
 
 def get_product_name
  p product
  self
 end
 
 def get_cost_customer
  p "$#{customer_buy}"
  self
 end

 def get_product_quantity
  p "You have #{quantity} #{product}"
  self
 end

 def set_sell_by
  #some code...
  self
 end

 def get_sell_by
  if sell_by < 5
   p "You need to sell this item within five days."
   self
  else
   p "Item doesn't currently need to be sold."
   self
  end
 end
end

apples = Grocery_Inventory.new("apples", 1.00, 5, 123, 0.25)
apples.get_product_name
apples.get_cost_customer
apples.get_product_quantity
```

Comment: You already do *exactly* what you are asking about in your `initialize` method. So, clearly, it *is* possible. Also, what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby is very lax in this regard. Simply access a variable with `@`and if it doesn't exist it will be created.

```
def set_sell_by
    @sell_by = value
    self
end
```

Comment: To be more precise: *every* object is *always* created empty. The *only possible way* to add an instance variable to an object is *after* it is created, and (almost) the only possible way to execute code in Ruby is using methods, so pretty much *every* instance variable *ever* is added after the object is created using a method. Typically, those methods are either called `<instance_variable_name>=` or `initialize`.